# How can I get current song information

Tags: multimedia, mp3-tag

I want to know how can I get the current song information (*title*, *artist*, *album* etc) no matter what player is running.  I saw some KDE widget can do that.

How can I do that? is there any standard protocol or interface to get song information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command to get list of all media playing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298707/command-to-get-list-of-all-media-playing)

Comment: @PabloBianchi Thanks. It does answer my question. But after 10 years my neurons' links were garbage collected. I can't recall anything.

Answer (score 3):

A simple method from the command line would be to read the output from pulseaudio to list properties of a sink input by running the following command in a terminal

```
pacmd list-sink-inputs
```

By this we can see the application that initiated a stream as well as other song properties from metatags (including artist, title, etc.) if available.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard protocol to do that, the widget you're talking about are just handling a lot of protocols. For exemple, Amarok has is own way, VLC another etc...