# Command to get list of all media playing

Tags: command-line, pulseaudio, alsa, media

I want to get a list of all media playing. Somewhat like the notification bar shows you. Is there a command to do the same?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That feature s implemented with [`MPRIS`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/) (Media Player Remote Interfacing Specification), a standard [D-Bus interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus).

### D-Bus with `dbus-send`

You can control it with DBUS commands manually, but I find it "a little bit" complicated for everyday use:

```bash
# Get current Status
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify \
  /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
  string:'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' \
  string:'PlaybackStatus'

# Get Metadata of currently playing song (if Playing)
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify \
  /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
  string:'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' \
  string:'Metadata'
```

*(Spotify is the player, change that accordingly)*

### [`playerctl`](https://github.com/acrisci/playerctl)

Or simply use `playerctl`:

```bash
playerctl status
playerctl metadata
```

Install with `apt`:

```bash
sudo apt install playerctl
```

### [Python's D-Bus module](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/)

You can also control players with `python`'s `dbus` module:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
for service in bus.list_names():
    if service.startswith('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.'):
        player = dbus.SessionBus().get_object(service, '/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2')

        status=player.Get('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player', 'PlaybackStatus', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        print(status)

        metadata = player.Get('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player', 'Metadata', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        print(metadata)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me a bit more? This was not in the question but its what I'm trying to achieve.

Say, you have 2 audio playing. And then you pause the 1st audio. Now only the 2nd audio is playing. So, when you press F5 (to pause music) the 2nd audio should gets paused, right? Well, it doesn't. The first audio then plays with the 2nd audio.

So, I want the audio which was last played to be play/pause by the F5 key, but this isn't the default gnome behavior. Do you think you can help me?

Comment: Pause the playing only is easy, as you can check `PlaybackStatus`, which will return *Playing*. But not sure if it's possible to know which player was playing last (the [Interface declaration](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/Player_Interface.html#Property:PlaybackStatus) does not have yield like that). You may track the Status with a never-ending loop or so, but it seems not very nice to me.

Comment: Thanks.Also, What's `PlaybackStatus`? How can I execute it?

Comment: See my updated answer